# Groovy - Add Map Entry with Iterator

Tags: groovy, dictionary

Please explain, why this isn't working (Groovy 2.0.5 on JDK7). I just want to add some map entries from a list.

```
def map = new HashMap<String,String>()
map << ["key":"value"]

def list = ["a","b","c"]
list.each {
    map << [it:"value"]
}
println map
println map.a
println map.containsKey("a")

/*
[key:value, a:value, b:value, c:value]
null        <- ?
false       <- ?
*/
```

It is also not working with:

```
map << ["$it":"value"]
```

But it is working with:

```
map << [(""+it):"value"]
```

???

Answer (score 14):

This

```
map << [it:"value"]
```

Just uses a key called `it`.  If you wrap it in parentheses:

```
map << [(it):"value"]
```

It works as you wanted...

If you do:

```
map << ["$it":"value"]
```

Then, you can see that you have a `GStringImpl`: as a key rather than a `java.lang.String`

```
println map.keySet()*.getClass().name
// prints [GStringImpl, GStringImpl, String, GStringImpl ]
```

(package names omitted for brevity)

Then, you try and look up a GString key with a String, and this fails (see the *'GStrings aren't Strings'* section [on this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString))

This works:

```
map << [(""+it):"value"]
```

As it just creates a String (by appending `it` to the empty String)

Anyway...long story short, use `[(it):'value']`